# Webstorm Angularjs Support

Tags: angularjs, templates, intellisense, webstorm

I am using Webstorm 8, which is the latest version. Jetbrains included angular support in this version. But I can't see any intellisense or any templates being added when we try to add File -> New Item related to angular such as controller, factory etc. Is there any option I need to set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS plugin doesn't include any angular-specific file templates, so no Angular-specific actions are available in File/New. But it comes with a set of live templates you can use to create controllers, etc. - Settings/Live Templates/AngularJS
See also http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/creating-code-constructs-by-live-templates.html

As for intellisense, it should work for specific HTML attributes as well as for controllers, directives and other stuff. Do you have angular.js file (uncompressed) in your project? see http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/03/angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm/ for some tips

Comment: Thanks @lena. saw the intellisense working in html. Was thinking intellisence will work in js files for angular keywords as well. Also, added new templates in the File -> New by going through File -> Settings -> File and Code Templates in webstorm.

Answer (score 3):

John Papa has produced some helpful file templates (and snippets). These are his simple WEBSTORM directions:

AngularJS snippets and file templates that follow these styles and guidelines. You can import them into your WebStorm settings:

1. Download the [WebStorm AngularJS file templates and snippets](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide/blob/master/assets/webstorm-angular-file-template.settings.jar?raw=true)
2. Open WebStorm and go to the *File* menu
3. Choose the *Import Settings* menu option
4. Select the file and click *OK*

In a JavaScript file type these commands followed by a TAB:

```
ng-c // creates an Angular controller
ng-f // creates an Angular factory 
ng-m // creates an Angular module
```

source: http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjs-snippets-for-sublime-visual-studio-and-webstorm/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice James. I updated the answer to include the essential parts of the answer here and provided the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

i think all the support gives you is built in knowledge of ng-directives (for autocomplete). That said, [take a look here](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/using-angularjs.html) and see if you've completed the steps to add Angular as a library?